# Typescript 2.8: Remove properties in one type from another

Tags: typescript, typescript2.8, conditional-types

In the [changelog of 2.8](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html), they have this example for conditional types:

```
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;  // Remove types from T that are assignable to U
type T30 = Diff<"a" | "b" | "c" | "d", "a" | "c" | "f">;  // "b" | "d"
```

I want to do that except remove the properties of an object. How can I achieve the following:

```
type ObjectDiff<T, U> = /* ...pls help... */;

type A = { one: string; two: number; three: Date; };
type Stuff = { three: Date; };

type AWithoutStuff = ObjectDiff<A, Stuff>; // { one: string; two: number; }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, leveraging your `Diff` type from earlier (which by the way is the same as the `Exclude` type which is now part of the standard library), you can write:

```
type ObjectDiff<T, U> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, keyof U>>;
type AWithoutStuff = ObjectDiff<A, Stuff>; // inferred as { one: string; two: number; }
```