# Remove properties of a type from another type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.8, conditional-types

This question is similar, but a bit different from [Typescript 2.8: Remove properties in one type from another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49564342/1454406)

I would like to create a function that takes a type, and returns a new type that doesn't include properties that are of type Array or are other complex (nested) objects.

I'm assuming conditional types are the best (only?) way to handle this? How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you considered leveraging `Record` to map all complex properties to let's say either undefined or null and `Pick` those properties that are neither of those?

Comment: Alternatively I'd cosider just using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and dynamically populate an object based on a predicate function.

Comment: I've only use the .NET port -- which is awesome, but maybe something like this would be helpful? https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a conditional type that only preserved primitive types (excludes arrays and other objects) using conditional types (to pick out the keys) and `Pick`

```
type PrimitiveKeys<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Exclude<T[P], undefined> extends object ? never : P
}[keyof T];
type OnlyPrimitives<T> = Pick<T, PrimitiveKeys<T>>

interface Foo {
    n: number;
    s: string;
    arr: number[];
    complex: {
        n: number;
        s: string;
    }
} 

let d : OnlyPrimitives<Foo> // will be { n: number, s: string }
```

The actual function implementation should be pretty simple, just iterate the object properties and exclude `object`

```
function onlyPrimitives<T>(obj: T) : OnlyPrimitives<T>{
    let result: any = {};
    for (let prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] !== 'object' && typeof obj[prop] !== 'function') {
            result[prop] = obj[prop]
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let foo = onlyPrimitives({ n: 10, s: "", arr: [] }) ;
```

**Edit** Added correct handling for optional fields.

Comment: This works with the example you have, but does not work with a `DeepPartial` type I have defined:

```ts
export type DeepPartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Array<infer UArray>
    ? Array<DeepPartial<UArray>>
    : T[P] extends ReadonlyArray<infer UReadonlyArray> ? ReadonlyArray<DeepPartial<UReadonlyArray>> : DeepPartial<T[P]>
};
```
usage example like: `pickPrimitives({} as DeepPartial<Foo>)`
So I'm currently working at tweaking the typings to see if I can figure out what's wrong and fix it

Comment: Actually, it's not even directly about the `DeepPartial` type, this just doesn't work when the type has `undefined` in its type domain, such as when the property is optional. This makes sense I guess, since a type of `ComplexObject | undefined` isn't necessarily of type `object`. I was able to get this working (as far as I can tell) by changing `[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? never : P` to `[P in keyof T]: Exclude<T[P], undefined> extends object ? never : P`

Comment: @MikeHaas yeah, I didn't test with optional fields... I'll update the answer to include your change