# Typescript type that checks if a given key if passed to as a key to an object resolves to an array

Tags: typescript

This is kind of a theoretical question but I was wondering if we can build an input type that checks if a given enum key if passed to as a key to an object resolves to an array. I guess this is better explained with an example:

```js
enum FormKeys {
  a = "a",
  b = "b",
}

interface IInitalFormValues {
  [FormKeys.a]: number
  [FormKeys.b]: string[]
}

const initialFormValues: IInitalFormValues = {
  [FormKeys.a]: 123,
  [FormKeys.b]: ["a"],
}

function onChange(input: FormKeys) {
  /*
    Error here since if we pass FormKeys.a then assigning an array to
    type number is an error
  */
  initialFormValues[input] = []
}

onChange(FormKeys.b)
```

What we can obviously do here is to change `input: FormKeys` to `input: FormKeys.b` but this solution does not scale well, is there a way to do it more generically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick out the keys that are for array types by doing this (I picked this up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837544/157247)):

```typescript
type ArrayKeys<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends any[] ? Key : never;
}[keyof T];
```

(That's a bit tricky, full explanation below.) `ArrayKeys<IInitialFormValues>` would be just `FormKeys.b`, for instance, since that's the only property with an array type. If you had more, `ArrayKeys<IInitialFormValues>` would be a union of them.

Then your `input` parameter's type is `ArrayKeys<IInitialFormValues>`:

```typescript
function onChange(input: ArrayKeys<IInitialFormValues>) {
    initialFormValues[input] = [];
}
```

That way, this works:

```typescript
onChange(FormKeys.b);   // Works as desired
```

but this fails:

```typescript
onChange(FormKeys.a);   // Fails as desired
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9gJwgaWATwM5QN4CgoFQCGUAvFAEREUA0+hARmZQ7bgL664CWIALsAQAzIgGNgUAJKSQ3PtyIAbeEgBqSsMCx5CUANoqU6DADoiAXQBcUcBAaCA3PQIHERzCYZWoGPgl4A5nrmTpy4onAgvlC8cgrKbuqKmhjW0rLySoZJKcw6hK5IqB4W1gCMAEwAzHS6he6mXtZ6VBTmdOxOuHxoAA4SAIIICERoxRgAPAAqAHx5zvrFMSBQANbocEJQU95TesXmUMAAHgIgACZYRCBowVAA-FBL1iDAAG6OHHrraJvbIbgAPSA7YAC24WAhxEUGDgPjgEGA8kRWFB13OaBoUD4oLgYACoKgAHcJOdIgByPg2YDAc4xKmgwTASxAkE9fpQIYjNAAWWAdkEkymR1OoEuUDgDAAVsBRHw5uQAArcUSraZYrmjcbTGYzLpCMAgOXcSISkAAYTRIACwAAFLxemA+NZNWNjBN0nEsokNFoZgBKHALWKZBJqX0YPQOp2HcjBUJcSKW64222GcZmf0OQjA2BEbgw4hYc5abgIWm4JNW1Pp4yeLM5kEAdUQqyuxdL5fOQA)

---

How that `ArrayKeys` works:

```typescript
type ArrayKeys<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends any[] ? Key : never;
}[keyof T];
```

There are two stages to that:

1. The `{/*...*/}` part maps each property of `T` into a new mapped type where the type of the property is the key itself or `never`. Suppose we had:

   ```typescript
   type Example = {
       a: string[];
       b: number[];
       c: string;
   };
   ```

   Just the first part of `ArrayKeys` creates this anonymous type:

   ```typescript
   {
       a: "a";
       b: "b";
       c: never;
   }
   ```
2. Then the `[keyof T]` part at the end creates a union of the types of those properties, which in theory would be `"a" | "b" | never`, but `never` is always dropped from union types, so we end up with `"a" | "b"` — the keys of `Example` for properties with array types.

You can go a step further and build a type consisting of only the parts of `Example` that match that by using `Pick<Example, ArrayKeys<Example>>`, but you don't need that for this specific purpose.