# How to define a Type from a Class/Interface that includes only class members of specified types

Tags: typescript

Let me explain my idea in this example. Lets say I have this class:

```
class Class1 {
  f1!: string;
  f2!: string;
  f3!: number;
  f4!: Date;
}
```

If I need a type with the members of types `string` from that class.
I can do for example

```
type Class1Stings = Omit<Class1, 'f3' | 'f4'>;
```

But I need to know exact properties names for this. I want to have something like this:

```
type Class1Stings = KeepOnlyTypes<Class1, string>;
// or 
type Class1Stings = RemoveTypes<Class1, number | Date>;
```

Is this possible?

============= **Edit**:

[my playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

============= **Edit2**:

[Complete solution for what I wanted, if some1 need it...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but you can do it by first finding the keys for those properties (using a trick I picked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837544/157247)), then using `Pick` as you indicated.

```typescript
type PickStringProps<Source extends object> = Pick<Source, {
    [Key in keyof Source]: Source[Key] extends string ? Key : never;
}[keyof Source]>;

// Usage:

class Class1 {
    f1!: string;
    f2!: string;
    f3!: number;
    f4!: Date;
}

type Class1Strings = PickStringProps<Class1>;
//   ^?
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYGVgCc4DsDmN0D2YAzgDwoECu6C0EAHsBFgCbFQEBGAVhAsAD4oAXliIk5KjQgAaKAG8AUFBVQA2gGkIIKNihJtBAGZQK1WgF0AXKam1N2i1AZNW7Yhmw4oAfihadGywIADcIdABuRQBfNQMQY1tzCAsBKMUAegyoAFViAEMcCCtFRQQAG3zidgBhSuqARgVlVSMGgEIbD0xcKNUoIwAmTqhurz7WgGYRrEoAW05wiZUjABYRgBF8pijo0tBIKDqq4ga0Hpx2UXhkc698IjJjxrTM7JUAPR9FIA) (Explanation below.)

Alternatively, here's a reusable generic version:

```typescript
// A type that picks out the keys for properties from `Source` that are
// assignable to `PickType`
type KeysByType<Source extends object, PickType> = {
    [Key in keyof Source]: Source[Key] extends PickType ? Key : never;
}[keyof Source];

// A type that picks the properties from `Source` that are assignable to `Picktype`
type PickByType<Source extends object, PickType> =
    Pick<Source, KeysByType<Source, PickType>>;
```

*(We could combine the two above, but this is a bit clearer.)*

Usage:

````typescript
class Class1 {
    f1!: string;
    f2!: string;
    f3!: number;
    f4!: Date;
}

type Class1Strings = PickByType<Class1, string>;
//   ^?```
````

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Copying from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855968/157247), here's how `KeysByType` works — there are two parts to it:

1. The `{/*...*/}` part maps each property of `Source` into a new mapped type where the type of the property is the key itself or `never`. Suppose we had:

   ```typescript
   type Example = {
       a: string;
       b: string;
       c: number;
   };
   ```

   Just the first part of `KeysByType<Example, string>` creates this anonymous type:

   ```typescript
   {
       a: "a";
       b: "b";
       c: never;
   }
   ```
2. Then the `[keyof Source]` part at the end creates a union of the types of those properties, which in theory would be `"a" | "b" | never`, but `never` is always dropped from union types, so we end up with `"a" | "b"` — the keys of `Example` for properties with array types.

Then to create `PickByType`, we use `Pick` as you indicated.

---

In a comment you've asked why this doesn't seem to be working [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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):

```typescript
function assignDates<T extends Class1>(
    obj: T,
    source: Record<KeysByType<T, Date>, string> | undefined,
    keys: KeysByType<T, Date>[]
): void {
    if (source) {
        for (const key of keys) {
            if (source[key] !== undefined) {
                obj[key] = new Date(source[key]);
                // ^^−−− Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'T[KeysByType<T, Date>]'.(2322)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*(Note that I've updated that a bit from [your original](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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): I changed the name `json` to `source` since its value isn't JSON [that would be a string], and fixed the type so you don't need the `as any` on `source[key]`: its values are strings, not Dates, and from the code it appears to be optional.)*

It took me a while to understand why that didn't work too. :-) The answer is: It *is* working, but the `assignDates` function isn't typesafe, because although `Class1`'s `Date` properties are specifically `Date`, subclasses of it can refine those to a `Date` subtype:

```typescript
class MyDate extends Date {
    myNiftyMethod() { /*...*/ }
}
class Class2 extends Class1 {
    f4: MyDate;
    // ...
}
```

`Class2` fits the type constraint `extends Class1` so you could pass it into `assignDates`, but `f4` isn't *just* a `Date` anymore, it's a `MyDate`, and so you can't assign a `Date` to it.

Of course, [a non-generic version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-HWoXK6m1fRSJo4lhiJUjT9KwQaUHIlFWnOCOb4kGCNDWgAlWLMUKeAkQ4mX68V5NpRJ+10MgAH1ALdQgQeguVCG8PWqAhWnfIkvC-RJKzSIpGgUZVWhmYgsFZRcCkbUAaTvXEu0Ij17mYEimU0J0qgmDY4IooMqMKYjSOhNYulAO1MmyMCIKg1j2LEwozx4mBumyaYeR-YIuNxKTGmVaNxIKNNxK0woRwNPcGLPLJQDk0BL09TslgPLQjxpM9Ehye5Y1aAByT0AAZPU9ABadzY28z1zQsc1PWadz3OaABWYNFXcyKAE4AC0XNAZZEiKFy4xc1SliAA) of `assignDate` has that same `Class2` problem, but doesn't raise an error on the `obj[key]` assignment. I expect this is some kind of limitation of TypeScript.

Given that the non-generic version doesn't have an error, you might just tell TypeScript to ignore the error, but you might want to post a question (since we're pretty far afield of the original question you asked here) asking whether there's a way to write a generic version in a typesafe way. (If you do, please link to it in the comments below; I'll be interested to see the answers.)

Comment: Very nice approach and beautiful solution! I always forgetting about `never`. I tried to use your code to write a function that initialize `Date` fields from string, but getting an error that confuse me a bit. Can you please review my code? (I added lik to the question)

Comment: @Dimanoid - The issue there isn't `PickByType`, but rather that `assignDates` itself isn't typesafe. I've added to the end of the answer to explain why. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and excellent explanation!