# Array of enum to record type

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function that takes a parameter of an array of enum values:

```
enum HatType {
  Big,
  Flat,
}

const fn = (types: HatType[]) => {
  ...
};

fn([ HatTypes.Big ]);
```

and within `fn`, I return properties on the return type based upon what enum values are passed:

```
const hatResults = fn([ HatTypes.Big ]);
// Returns `{ bigHats: BigHat[] }`
const moreHatResults = fn([ HatTypes.Flat ]);
// Returns `{ flatHats: FlatHat[] }`
const allTheHatResults = fn([ HatTypes.Big, HatTypes.Flat ]);
// Returns `{ bigHats: BigHat[], flatHats: FlatHat[] }`
```

Is it possible to type the return value based upon the enum values I've passed in? That is, `{ bigHats: BigHat[] }` or `{ flatHats: FlatHat[] }` or `{ bigHats: BigHat[], flatHats: FlatHat[] }` for the above

I'm thinking that I could possibly by having a union type from the enum array and using `Pick<AllHats, pickedHatsUnion>` to do this. But this requires the `as const` assignment to the array to generate the union correctly, which I couldn't find a way to do with a function parameter.

Is this possible?

---

`AllHats` is an exemplar type, but would be something like:

```
interface AllHats {
  bigHats: BigHat[],
  flatHats: FlatHat[],
  fancyHats: FancyHat[],
}
```

etc. Each hat would be a simple object type - if I'm understanding correctly, knowing what the structure of that further is not needed to answer this question, as the function will take care of that.

---

In fact there's one piece of implementation missing - the hat map!

```
interface HatMap extends Record<HatType, string> {
  [HatType.Big]: 'bigHats',
  ...
}
```

which may be useful to generate the return type (such as it is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygFgQwA7ACoE8VQN4CgoGwCKAqgIIBKAolALxQBEAzgI5gIBOwDANPodQDCqMgDkA4gBka9BlwDGAFwQgA5gBtufQlEEBJCoOl1G8gJYd5m3rgC%20uXGZCLgHAGYJ5wKHvjJveDoA1k4AJgBcsIgoGCgA3HaOzq4eXrBsnN7AAB4uIKFMPn5YgYQh%20ZHFaJjAAHQwpJRUCTpMZgBewJHgEABGrgn2Ti7unt4UwEoqGlm5oAVF0QH8BOURUf6xdUIiEtIthADuZqGKcN2Q-RwHBHDAZqpwihd9A4nDKWO6FlazeQu%20JY4FZQNaVJZbWr6Qz7EEcBChMxgJgvK6DByKGpQABqCHUYGAAHk3AAeVAAPhMqAA2kFgOgAPZuKCoAC6CSSI1S3iqAFlkFAcv9ChN5AyOKESVUtjxFv5KaUCNTpTV6o1qKzKhkuDcoMqIaqdmIpFRNVBRco1JpdfrNqroUZTZFBD9rXYEpisFUTLj8UTSXzkOSOW4wCAlGYGSAoJkEAAKFEbFAASmBrWOinkcCgCdqa1Tip0UHkCCYPINKDV5GokS4ijAHGjTFqbU6UAAVFBm63gLqdCWy0nqpWjXsqLXgPXG13ancHk8OzPjqc4H3CAPy3bKw7pBOp9H%20WdagAFPSL5vwxHIjudgBMuvstiAA)). Please feel free to create your own map if required to answer the question

---

In the worst case, the above would be dependent upon some property of the type. Each `Hat` type (e.g., `BigHat`) would extend the following interface:

```
interface IHat {
  kind: HatType;
}
```

Comment: What are `BigHat`, `FlatHat`, `FancyHat`? How do they differ? It's really hard to answer without all of these pieces filled in.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm really wanting to avoid these being type-specific. What I was hoping for was a way that, given an enum with an object whose key corresponds to the type, I could simply pick those properties. I really don't want it to be dependent on the input types' properties. If it is the case that that's not possible, I will add detail to the types for this purpose, but I really want to avoid this

Comment: It's not about being type-specific, it's about providing (as you put it) exemplars so that the answers really apply to what you're describing. If you leave it to us to make these things up, aside from that asking us to spend much more time on your problem, it also means we can easily make them up the wrong way, wasting our time and yours. Specifics are important for checking that answers really work, for one thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The problem with that is that if I give you an exemplar instance type, the answer becomes dependent upon those details. I may want to use this pattern with other types that may have an entirely different interface to each other

Comment: Not in my experience. Specific types can be swapped out. But we need **something** to work from, to be sure we're solving the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to type the return value based upon the enum values I've passed in?

Only if the enum values passed in are compile-time constants. When the type is just `HatType`, you'll get the entirety of `AllHats`.

> ...which I couldn't find a way to do with a function parameter.

You can do that with a generic type parameter.

I've come up with two ways to do it.

#### The first way

The first way uses `AllHats` and `HatMap` from the question (but I know you've said they're just examples). Since we need to pick properties from `AllHats` based on their *value* type, we need something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71970717/how-to-define-a-type-from-a-class-interface-that-includes-only-class-members-of/71970801#71970801) to do that:

```typescript
// A type that picks out the keys for properties from `Source` that are
// assignable to `PickType`
type KeysByType<Source extends object, PickType> = {
    [Key in keyof Source]: Source[Key] extends PickType ? Key : never;
}[keyof Source];

// A type that picks the properties from `Source` that are assignable to `PickType`
type PickByType<Source extends object, PickType> =
    Pick<Source, KeysByType<Source, PickType>>;
```

As you said, we can map the generic type parameter from `HatType` to the type of hat via `HatMap`, then we can use pick out the properties of `AllHats` based on those types:

```typescript
const fn = <T extends HatType>(types: T[]): PickByType<AllHats, HatMap[T][]> => {
    // ...implementation...
};
```

Test cases:

```typescript
const hatResults = fn([ HatType.Big ]);
hatResults.bigHats
hatResults.flatHats // <=== Example error, no `flatHats` on it because `HatType.Flat` wasn't included
const moreHatResults = fn([ HatType.Flat ]);
moreHatResults.flatHats
const twoHatsResults = fn([ HatType.Big, HatType.Flat ]);
twoHatsResults.bigHats
twoHatsResults.flatHats

declare let e1: HatType;
declare let e2: HatType;
const unknownHats = fn([e1, e2]);
unknownHats.bigHats
unknownHats.flatHats
unknownHats.fancyHats
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQFwTwBwKbQBYEMqjgSwMYGsBnUAewFcMpkk8EYiAzYgJ0yeMSaiwQbYFtQAAwDKZJjgSCU6UKiYIAsACgQsggSwBzAHaoARgBskUYkIAKuPABV4k5bESgA0rQIAhGDcQAeUaXFICAAeUAjaACZExHoAVgg4UAA0oBb4XggAfKAAvKAA3sqgRaAA2i4woFjaoDQwxPSgfgEAugBcjWISZbTNoMGhEUSp1ragAPzOtKDt2ggAbghMANzKAL4ltfUd-hLNK0rKqpAOxmgY2PhElEhwbBxcPKD0-EJNElKUMnJIqOpauoZjKZBMN0oJ7KNhh50r5OoEQmFIiRYvEkilLOkstlCsVhrCdghkuV3J5bPiAslQbYMhl9sowqQBAAJdDpfI4opuLSJDmgABiBnQPKUxX5qG0OBgwtWymUVVCTHoqAkoBZGAKIuKGgAXggZoy9It9jKDkp5YslSquZo1X0EYNVTINaKAPpuk5ul3tABEei03ulcu0CstSAF6Ft-URRFtzuKno9bp99EFUADayDIeVYfFksj9qRsd5CdsnuTuZg6aUJszFuzEAMBjVRDjRT9NvQBHa1rVJWawtFKYjnfa4agvf7vKVEpgzdHFYngdNJ0dUAAsqg4Dl2ZqiiU1ekAHTWtqgHtC3n71m2Q9j09jtUD4pXqBHvkV+8Li-V2VKHDEbQCAwehqlybwrDtAZC2vRAMgAChOLtQCsPsAEp2ihUkfHARtm2SNUNzgEorGaPssSyVtQFUQ8aKwPg4CMPgwigdAsAAmjD15eQoH8aptFIRs1FkbQYGNOk-wAoDQDOAAlHgBKgIhchAuCSlXI9rVAZpUP2VRigAPTGZRZPkgxFMPdtm2M9A5IIBSCEPIdx07KiwG8bIPNAABRIJUHoow+iYNgmGSbRgSc5spAAyoMENHBUFIAgkEEA8bzHKQAHdfm0AByDAqhwAxSHCBBwmUf9AIwPhmAQNVbPs7cVLU1LEFvVMtJ0w4wAMoylGq+Q6tM8yIs7crJIoDLiGbeqzKUp5tFU9Sb2tfCYIQNqZG03TuqKQz7Em6ahocyzRqUKADs7GbhtTKzTRKwrvlAIwMAQABGdoWoQfZ7sFeQnoQF6ACYPrW-YKqk0htDwMKMu0ZtGoWko3uSBBAa2rrRT2pRIeh4hYebCytFunGYbhztHJu06Sbxsnhq-RTlCAA)

That works, but the type hint you get for (say) `twoHatsResults` above is just `PickByType<AllHats, (BigHat | FlatHat)[]>`, which isn't all that helpful.

#### The second way

There's another way —and it's much simpler — if we redefine `HatMap` as a union of the object types we want (and then we don't need `AllHats` at all):

```typescript
type HatMap = {
    [HatType.Big]: {bigHats: BigHat[]},
    [HatType.Flat]: {flatHats: FlatHat[]},
    [HatType.Fancy]: {fancyHats: FancyHat[]},
}
```

Now if we define `fn` as returning `HatMap[T]`, we'll get a union of those object types — `{bigHats: BigHat[]} | {flatHats: FlatHat[]}` for instance. But we don't want a union, we want an *intersection*.

[jcalz to the rescue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/157247):

```typescript
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
    (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
```

So now `fn` is:

```typescript
const fn = <T extends HatType>(types: T[]): UnionToIntersection<HatMap[T]> => {
    // ...implementation...
};
```

When we throw our test cases at it, the type hints are more useful:

```typescript
const hatResults = fn([ HatType.Big ]);
//    ^? { bigHats: BigHat[]; }
hatResults.bigHats
hatResults.flatHats // <=== Example error, no `flatHats` on it because `HatType.Flat` wasn't included
const moreHatResults = fn([ HatType.Flat ]);
//    ^? { flatHats: FlatHat[]; }
moreHatResults.flatHats
const twoHatsResults = fn([ HatType.Big, HatType.Flat ]);
//    ^? { bigHats: BigHat[]; } & { flatHats: FlatHat[]; }
twoHatsResults.bigHats
twoHatsResults.flatHats

declare let e1: HatType;
declare let e2: HatType;
const unknownHats = fn([e1, e2]);
//    ^?
//    { bigHats: BigHat[]; } & { flatHats: FlatHat[]; } & { fancyHats: FancyHat[]; }
unknownHats.bigHats
unknownHats.flatHats
unknownHats.fancyHats
```

`{ bigHats: BigHat[]; } & { flatHats: FlatHat[]; }` isn't as nice as `{ bigHats: BigHat[]; flatHats: FlatHat[]; }` would have been, but it's much more informative than `PickByType<AllHats, (BigHat | FlatHat)[]>`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAEghgFwCoE8AOwoG8CwAoKQqAIQEsBzAGnyKgDEAbRagouuEAYxRYF998pEAmAAnAGZxOmeAmw0iAZ1IAvYAC4o4CACMxAbnz88g4WMnSSFWVGAAPESAAmi2InmtCAfR8J0wHy9NACIdCmC+UxEJKUxGRBt7Rxc3OVxPKEC-DECQ8SYECKMo81j6Dm5Eh1AUm3TaLP9cqGDJLhQivGN8bMwAVRBSAHsQJCGASTNRRWBOBGGQAB4+gD4oAF4oBUIACj7baudXDhQoAH4oHYBrTT6ASnWVgDch0icoTRBgJ7E7g+TXDtrpohOIxFBxg9nq8nH8LuMPlpvmIBHheqkALJwNAbDy0ADaslQGAAdGRyABdTRYMLkWSKTTk2T4im8FgEon+EnxBBU7D5BKIBn0ArM1nsoiExDE4DciooPlYNqVIWadjtMVs4omPCcEaKOTiEC4xZIf41VycjArHa9YVIFl3W6DEZjSbRGZzBaLWRYtD4pAUtaPPFEAD0YagJOjpAgaAYwAgoAQiAW0ZJ2ygomACDAomN4AYDCgcGOIBQhi6lfwepABqgAAtEAAlYCKMAMBCuTZGnb41IyskUKAUu6ViO0AB6Z3wE6IWCgtPpjOsiBZ+igxibCFb7c7ihJS6F+G3u47XZJAoQ9KgE8W6wfUAAonY4HGE7ZRKIhqJKFohlAAAGV70oBUAjFApByHonBwGAMxAVaso8mBADupYgAA5HIQicAwYBOMATg1vqcgQD+wCyGe+64r2-ZIdyBQjmOs6RkQ06sbQC4gaqIqCgg66bvg5HZlRbbngePFdiRdZyAgqFDPS1FdrRIB9gOXLkn+DE8sx45sYQHF4HOhALkeXYrnSa4UhuvBQAAZNgUBScKPJirZPQKUp4n7oeq7SWiXlCspkmiseOqEXhcDZlACZyMAACMmhIZWkVMDFcW2AATMl0r+JWtb1mAIBXCAQyoSAN49mp+KJX+wBZaO+lTjOxkGU55nCky1m2Q5TkuWqYUCTZm59dx8rLuUGo9UJeDFaV5WVUKflWQF81lRV9KXkNij4Oti1bcqKD0vgQA)

Comment: This looks great! It would be incredible to get the returned type to be an object with keys to make the type easier to grok (e.g., `const hatResults = fn([ HatType.Big ]);` having `hatResults` of `{ bigHats: BigHat[]; }`), but that is icing-on-the-cake desirability. Is that possible?

Comment: @NickBull - Do you mean the type displayed by the IDE? Yeah, `PickByType<AllHats, BigHat[]>` is a bit hard to follow. I mean, `hatResults` **is** `{ bigHats: BigHat[] }`, but that's not what the type hint TypeScript gives the IDE says. (The times TS does and doesn't expand those tend to surprise me.) Let's see....

Comment: @NickBull - Got it, I've updated the answer. It actually got simpler (which may be why TypeScript expands the type, I don't know :-) ).