# How to use variable name as object reference in typescript/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an interface called GenerationInterface:

```
export default interface GenerationInterface{
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  latitude?: string;
  longitude?: string;
  source?: string;
  max_power?: number;
  current_power?: number;
}
```

I'm using MUI input fields like this:

```
                    <TextField
                      margin="dense"
                      id="latitude"
                      label="Latitude"
                      type="text"
                      name="latitude"
                      fullWidth
                      variant="standard"
                      value={currentGeneration.latitude}
                      onChange={handleGenerationFormChange}
                    />
```

Ignoring the fact that some of the elements are numeric and some are strings - let's pretend they're all strings - how can I use the passed name as a key for the interface to set elements of the interface with elegant code?  This is my attempt:

```
    const handleGenerationFormChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
      let genHolder = currentGeneration;

      genHolder[event.target.name as keyof GenerationInterface] = event.target.value;
      
    }
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: `Generation` or `GenerationInterface`? You seem to be using them interchangeably.

Comment: typo. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the assignment, you have to reassure TypeScript that the key you're trying to use identifies a string property in `Generation`.

There are a couple of ways to do that.

#### Generic Extracting String/Number Properties and Type Predicates

You can use a generic like this to get the keys for properties that are assignable to a given type:

```typescript
type AssignableKeys<Source extends object, Target> = Exclude<{
    [Key in keyof Source]: Required<Source>[Key] extends Target ? Key : never;
}[keyof Source], undefined>
```

*(More about how that works in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970801/157247), which is derived [no pun!] from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837544/157247) by [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir).)*

Then a type predicate to narrow the type of the string key you're using (this version repeats property names, but keep reading); notice the `AssignableKeys<Generation, string>` type at the end, saying the key identifies a string-typed property of `Generation`:

```typescript
function isGenerationStringKey(key: string): key is AssignableKeys<Generation, string> {
    switch (key) {
        case "name":
        case "latitude":
        case "longitude":
        case "source":
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

...and/or a type assertion function that *asserts* the key is valid:

```typescript
function assertIsGenerationStringKey(key: string): asserts key is AssignableKeys<Generation, string> {
    if (!isGenerationStringKey(key)) {
        throw new Error(`Key "${key}" doesn't specify a string-typed Generation property`);
    }
}
```

Then your function can use the type predicate to narrow the type of the key:

```typescript
const handleGenerationFormChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    let genHolder = currentGeneration;
    const key = event.target.name;
    if (isGenerationStringKey(key)) {
        genHolder[key] = event.target.value;
    }
};
```

or with the type assertion function:

```typescript
const handleGenerationFormChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    let genHolder = currentGeneration;
    const key = event.target.name;
    assertIsGenerationStringKey(key);
    genHolder[key] = event.target.value;
};
```

Repeat it for the numeric properties; perhaps you'd have a separate event handler for those that converts `value` to `number` and uses a number-oriented type predicate.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgHElr6UZgJqBvcnCFxgAEwD8ALjjUAriABG9CsJkoQSKXADOMKDQDmK4QBsuwGLNGbpu-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-q9Bgk11UrgBsazVaHS6ZonsolVo1trSwFeyoAhFLzXLp4Y5x7Pd6fTBnTg4jIkN+DmzoGVAADVF8AAEj4PESnwOBRAgJBtGoAByeBtGqNBL1uFAF0MABaSpqlEVgjwtOAwBwapYAqIDNW7chezQXhdDgZ0UHGNp7wlAAxaAQAAYVYhwkAARj2N0kCxWhJGQdAYAAOgEtiNgOSSYB6AAJZYAFkABkR2oMBZBgA42g0Wg4AAHzgTTdOWGEaiIFATKQMztk9XZz1UZk4A2ah1IgExrCgMTWXZTihTSRjqGY3V9gk9h5JgBFNjk4MqwvK87xIh8NWfCpNVfRMhF8-zAvoXFITE+LaDkpL1hSjEUFOdLVB7YUouYwTRA47LuN4xShIAJjE5VqsbGSMAUwTlNUjTtL0gyjOc1zLOs+a7NGBzUGWhKtnczzTE2Hz2FKoKQsyBLwuoasOvgWLoVU2rkvktLqyHVcxyux8lS6d18urEqAqCiqKihOLHrqxE5Ma5rSgoIA)

#### Example Objects and Derived Types (and Type Predicates)

Often when I want names at compile-time and also at runtime (for instance, for type predicates), I do it by having example objects and deriving the type from them. In your case:

```typescript
// The example objects
// NOTE: You can put documentation comments on these properties,
// and the comments will be picked up by the derived types
const generationStrings = {
    name: "",
    latitude: "",
    longitude: "",
    source: "",
};
const generationNumbers = {
    id: 0,
    max_power: 0,
    current_power: 0,
};

// Deriving types:
type GenerationStringProperties = typeof generationStrings;
type GenerationNumberProperties = typeof generationNumbers;
type Generation = Partial<GenerationStringProperties & GenerationNumberProperties>;
```

The type predicate and/or type assertion function is simpler and doesn't repeat names

```typescript
function isGenerationStringKey(key: string): key is keyof GenerationStringProperties {
    return key in generationStrings;
}
function assertIsGenerationStringKey(key: string): asserts key is keyof GenerationStringProperties {
    if (!isGenerationStringKey(key)) {
        throw new Error(`Key "${key}" doesn't specify a string-typed Generation property`);
    }
}
```

The usage in the event handler is the same as above.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgeirgBUALJOJADxXABtmIAjAKyQYAzuTQQAdsPgBzJBKRQUMYJIDKMKMAkzhcALxwA3uThm4EjkgBcBfABpT5zsuAwArgBMbdx+bickjJuXj74Dk5mwhDuUGhhEQC+FOJSsvKKrpIAcu4gvIp6hib+wJ62AAx+5iAorAD6kADuipXVZmixRBIwjRAtUG3kyZQ0cAAiisAAbtoycDAAnmBIwtbkSytwAOIZSirqmnMACjgrsMCrBgvLSBCYcHIK+6oSGlo6whSbzLvPWRJcvlFKcIOcVFdDD97o89gCgQUoF8NrcdnCDhJrscUBcUJwADx-TIY94nM6KCF6ABkaP+GIRIPJF1WAD4KNRaIxmD84GAiJ5gGhlMwUBJPFRoDctihhMIKa84Jh3BIMAqccxhKAwNwoHBRZ44J5JAByeBEFbKCxWURKlUYuDAYREl6HD4yADSSEWAAoANZe2zSN0ASls-sWDr04ZhzoBpJ0oPBlz0JXMRA8UEx4YdmKexNe8d0FES5FtqsketlFIAkk70QWjjpPT7w4HGzJQ5W5bAo17I3Bow9YyT24n5VdU2ZgA9vQBCR3Dhtu5t+r3B4PGSL+BYMHBNCxIfcAUSgOCg3oABs2CAASIzhxL4Q0QVYSU1wYQrNDTiMoD-tgBaH4DUXCs+TBClFgvYMKH8EsSw5OAAFVhBQOR+xgJgPyschvDQFwiACJB4E6U95BgUCJFsSj2VSaQ4AYfVuEogAxaAQAAYUYnQkAARmub0kGmcjrGQdAYAAOi40U5CPYSenxAAJOgAFkABlqwkMB3BgI9uBAci4AAHzgZT1LoNgYAAQSIFA9KQAyehZDd9BZTd-G4dIJEUiBOG8XVDFI7oKPrSRYPMOj4GzQwhPIiSYBxORJMsAzwqnGcF1Ct52xXcN13c7czCeHy-MUABtcMAF1rlinp4sS4iJOmPF3CQNK4Hg2jJHo7jPGYrK2KgTjuLkAAmATapgUTiEk6SeLk8ilNUjStJ0+zHPgEyzLUizWGs2z1vI5yDDcyciK8kr-OuILyJordIoHPsYvkySEqgJKJJStqtxlbsYFrSjC1ytd2uK3z-Iqr1queuK3o+5rOFa4sKCAA)

Comment: Does this apply in the case I stipulated in my question?  I said, "forget that some of these are numbers, just assume they're all strings."

Comment: This is otherwise very helpful.  I'm still struggling with the basic question of "at what point is typescript going to understand that a thing is a string".  It seems like sometimes when I wrap code with an if statement testing it, it doesn't seem to take.  I guess I just have a lot to learn about typescript.

Comment: @froopydoop - Yes, this applies to your case, I just did make sure to have the escape clause for numbers as well since they were there and I figure you did want to handle them. I mostly ignored the fact some of them were numbers, but called out that you'll probably want to have a parallel event handler for the number case that uses a type predicate for keys that identify number properties. If **all** of the properties had string values, you could use `keyof Required<GenerationInterface>` or similar, but since your real interface had numbers, I didn't want to provide a half-solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a generic parameter:

```js
    const handleGenerationFormChange = <T extends keyof GenerationInterface>(event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
      let genHolder = currentGeneration;

      genHolder[event.target.name as T] = event.target.value as GenerationInterface[T];
    }
```

Comment: The problem with unchecked type assertions is that, almost inevitably, you end up getting them wrong. :-)

Comment: If I do that, genholder is no longer of type GenerationInterface, right?