# Is there a way to type a function that removes properties by name from an object in Typescript while retaining type safety (without typecasting)?

Tags: typescript

Following up on [this great answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49564483/1386201) which gives us the `ObjectDiff` (which I have renamed to `ObjectExclude` for the purposes below)

I have a function that takes an object, and a list of properties I'd like to remove from a clone of that object. How do I tell Typescript what is happening here? The type should be the object passed in, minus the properties whose keys are passed in afterward.

```
type ObjectExclude<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>;

function removeProps<T extends object, U extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  ...propNames: U[]
): SomeType { // What type should this actually be?
  const objClone = { ...obj };
  propNames.forEach(p => delete objClone[p]);
  return objClone;
}
```

`SomeType` seems like a thing that can be derived, but I always just end up typecasting.

For example how can I tell typescript that `b` below is type `{one: number, two: string}` without manually typecasting?

```
const a = {one: 1, two: '2', three: true};
const b = removeProps(a, 'three'); // TS should just know the type here.
```

Looking at the code as a person who knows JS or TS, it is clear enough that `b` is of type

```
interface B {one: number; two: string}
```

I want TS to know that as well, without needing to tell it.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript can construct an object type for you, based on the input strings you are using in your rest params. The implementation of `removeProps` below is exactly the same as above. Only the type definition has changed.

We construct a `Z` type for the sole purpose of excluding it from the `T` type.

```
function removeProps<T extends object, K extends keyof T, Z = {[P in K]: any}>(
  obj: T,
  ...propNames: K[]
): ObjectExclude<T, Z> {
  const objClone = { ...obj };
  propNames.forEach(p => delete objClone[p]);
  return objClone;
}
```

Now in your code (as of TS 3.2.2, but I believe this works all the way back to 2.8), you'll get this:

```
const a = {one: 1, two: '2', three: true};
const b = removeProps(a, 'three');
// Type for b: Pick<{one: number, two: string, three: boolean}, "one" | "two">
```

That basically means that the type is same as object `a`, but only containing properties `"one"` and `"two"`.

> Note: Technically the type of `Z` would be `{[P in K]: T[K]}`, but `any` works above because it is never used in any way: we only care about the properties, not the values, of `Z`.

---

#### Update:

@titian-cernicova-dragomir points out below that the whole `Z` type isn't even necessary. So really, all you need to get this done is

```
export function removeProps<T extends object, U extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  ...propNames: U[]
): Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, U>> {
  const objClone = { ...obj };
  propNames.forEach(p => delete objClone[p]);
  return objClone;
}
```

This just forgoes the `ObjectExclude` type by directly using the types from which it is composed.

Comment: `Z` is really not necessary. You can just type the return as `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>`.

Comment: Thanks for this guys - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you could use `Partial<T>`
as the return type

Comment: A partial makes everything optional. What I wanted was a type representing an object which had the same shape, but without certain properties. Not with certain properties marked as optional.

Comment: To further explain for folks who may not know: Typescript provides a generic type called `Partial<T>` which makes all properties optional. So if `type A = {one: number, two: string, three: boolean}`, then `Partial<A>` is the same as `{one?: number, two?: string, three?: boolean}`. What I was after in the question above was something that would yield a type that looked more like `{one: number, two: string}`. Moreover, I needed TS to come up with the type intelligently. (I will edit the question to be more clear.)